# Join custom type in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can I join and filter Entity Framework context with a list of custom objects?

```
    public class Car
    {
        public int CarId;
        public DateTime Start;
        public DateTime End;
    }

    List<Car> all = new List<Car>();

    //... code that fills all collection        
    var y = context.Car.Join(all,
                eua => eua.Car.UserID,
                euaP => all.Car.UserID, (e1, e2) => new { e1 });
                //Filter by date
```

I want to make something similar to

```
CREATE TABLE #Car
(
    ID uniqueidentifier,
    DateTimeStart datetime,
    DateTimeEnd datetime
)

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Car C
INNER JOIN #Car CTemp ON C.ID = CTemp.ID 
WHERE
    (DATEADD(s, 1, C.DateTimeStart) between CTemp.DateTimeStart AND  CTemp.DateTimeEnd)
    AND (DATEADD(s,1, C.DateTimeEnd between CTemp.DateTimeStart AND    CTemp.DateTimeEnd))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only join in-memory with in-memory objects. So joining in the database is not an option unless you load your in-memory objects into the database (at which point they're no longer in-memory). However you can filter in the database in very specific ways. For example, if you have a list of IDs you want to match you can use `Contains` like so:

```
List<Guid> ids = inMemoryCars.Select(o => o.ID).ToList();
List<Car> matchingCarsFromDB = context.Cars.Where(c =>  ids.Contains(c.ID)).ToList();
```